# Why are the assistants called Bobs (Bawbs?) on Cutthroat Kitchen?

Tags: reality-tv, cutthroat-kitchen

Often on *Cutthroat Kitchen*, Alton will ask his "Bobs"/"Bawbs" to bring in one of the nefarious devices to be used for the challenge. Any explanation for the nickname? Alton said it was an acronym on his Facebook live. So what does B.O.B stand for? Even though Alton said he hid it online I can't find it ANYWHERE.

Comment: Is there something more you're looking for in an answer?

Comment: Im pretty sure it stands for (Bring it out boys)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to IMDb.com on the [Cutthroat Kitchen page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2930446/trivia) it says,

> On Cutthroat Kitchen, Alton will ask his "BOB" to bring in one of the devices to be used for the challenge. BOB is acronym for Biomorphic Occupational roBot.

*[**EDIT:** This is likely based on Alton's own [explanation](https://twitter.com/altonbrown/status/625496167841804289) on his official Twitter page.*

[image]

*[And though I'm pretty sure it's just a jokey acronym Alton made up after the fact to explain the name, it's still [Word of God](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WordOfGod).]*

I hope that helps.

Comment: I don't know whether to post this as an answer or add it to this one, but there's [this](https://twitter.com/altonbrown/status/625496167841804289), from Alton's official Twitter account. People probably didn't find it because Alton used a post-it note instead of text. [And I'm pretty sure it's just a jokey acronym Alton made up *after the fact* to explain the name, but still, Word of God.]

Comment: I'd add it to this one. Besides, they could use the Rep.

Comment: OK, will do. Just wasn't sure if it's too different\intrusive. EDIT: Done. I hope that's OK, @Twobrite1022.

Comment: That would make it a backronym

Answer (score 5):

This is apparently a case of them utilizing the [Planet of Steves](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlanetOfSteves) trope on the show. The term isn't any sort of official kitchen or cooking term, or one for assistants. Alton Brown simply refers to his assitants as Bobs, or a group of people who are all named Bob.

There was even an After-Show episode which featured two of them demonstrating something for the judge. The official entry for this after-show on [Food Network's website](http://blog.foodnetwork.com/fn-dish/2015/07/cutthroat-kitchen-altons-after-show-810/) shows the assistants are simply refered to as Bobs.

So yeah, nothing special or significant, it's just what they're called on the show.

Comment: It could also be a reference to "the Bobs" from Office Space: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_iiOEQOtBlQ

Comment: This seems fairly implausible. Why would he make a reference to characters in a movie about working in an office on a cooking show? The characters in Office Space may be following the same Planet of Steves trope, but I'd find it highly odd that Alton Brown would decide to call all the stage hands Bob because of the movie.

Comment: I'd argue that Office Space is using the same trope. In my experience "the Bobs" has become a common phrase in places I've worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the source:

"The name Bob, which was used frequently when "greeking" name-brand products on Good Eats."

Here's a link to the reference: [TV Tropes site](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/CutthroatKitchen)

Answer (score 0):

I have been wondering about the BOBs on Cutthroat Kitchen too! I've read all of the answers given here and they all make sense but I will submit that BOBs stands for Beasts Of Burden because the BOBs are always waiting in the wings to fetch and carry at Alton's beck & call!!  :)

Comment: Are you guessing or is this based on actual evidence that that's what the production means Bob to be?

Answer (score -1):

Alton said it's short for thingamabobs.

Comment: Where\when did he say that? Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: Indeed. Please provide some kind of source to back up this answer.

Answer (score -3):

In the Michael Keaton Bat man movie. The Joker's main henchman was called Bob.

Since Alton is being evil and a prankster I wonder if that is it.

Comment: Can you explain why you think there would be any connection between these two things?